# Как не сериализовывать поле класса? Несколько вариантов

Tags: java, сериализация, serializable

Знаю что можно пометить поле класса ключевым словом `transient`, поле может быть `static` - оно не сериализуется, и вроде как можно использовать интерфейс `Externalizable`...
Прав ли я, и какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: чем вас вариант с `transient` не устраивает?

Comment: Externalizable - это тот же Serializable, но дает вам возможность сериализовать объект "руками" (то есть те поля, которые вам нужны). Ну и static, и transient тоже подходят. Больше способов, вроде как, нет

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov для сериализации руками есть жеж readObject/writeObject

Comment: @tym32167 это как раз методы, идущие с Externalizable

Comment: @ValentynAnzhurov действительно, что то я немного затупил :)